# macOS Mojave (10.14.6) + iTunes 12.9 + iOS 13.4.1 - Cannot, at all, transfer ringtones to device

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ringtones

Yes, I tried dragging them into the Tones screen.
Yes, I tried copypasting them in there instead.
Yes, I tried removing them all and adding them back.
Yes, I tried deleting the .plist config file inside the folder.
Yes, I even tried deleting the one outside the folder.
But still no dice. Nothing even showed signs of a transfer being supposed to take place.
:(
Does any of you kindly know anything else I could try?

Comment: ringtones have to have the ".m4r" file extension, do yours?

Comment: They also have tp be 40s or less

Comment: @SteveChambers I know and followed both those rules, most of them are ringtones I already had on my phone and had successfully synced before, and I used .m4r converters for the new ones instead of just editing the extension, as I had bad luck with that method in the past, so those should have no issue either.